Remove blank area of matplotlib between distance of zero for multivariate time series
I have two time series:

First row is prediction
second row is ground truth


I want remove this red area, where it should be flexible.

I mean there is no distance between them like this picture, without removing x-axis and y-axis

Here is my code, how do I do that?
#@title Animate Define

# Display Parameter
start = 0
end = 1024

Xt = X_unseen[start:end]
yp = y_pred[start:end]
yt = y_true[start:end]

# Get mask of every class for prediction
bl_pred = yp == 0
p_pred = yp == 1
qrs_pred = yp == 2
t_pred = yp == 3

# get mask of every class for ground truth
bl_true = yt == 0
p_true = yt == 1
qrs_true = yt == 2
t_true = yt == 3

# create figure with two rows and one column
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(20, 8))

# Plotting for prediction
prev_class = None
start_idx = start
for i in range(start, end):
    current_class = None
    if bl_pred[i]:
        current_class = 'grey'
    elif p_pred[i]:
        current_class = 'orange'
    elif qrs_pred[i]:
        current_class = 'green'
    elif t_pred[i]:
        current_class = 'purple'

    if current_class != prev_class:
        if prev_class is not None:
            ax1.axvspan(start_idx, i, color=prev_class, alpha=0.5)
        start_idx = i
        prev_class = current_class
# Fill the last region
if prev_class is not None:
    ax1.axvspan(start_idx, end, color=prev_class, alpha=0.5)

# Plotting for ground truth
prev_class = None
start_idx = start
for i in range(start, end):
    current_class = None
    if bl_true[i]:
        current_class = 'grey'
    elif p_true[i]:
        current_class = 'orange'
    elif qrs_true[i]:
        current_class = 'green'
    elif t_true[i]:
        current_class = 'purple'

    if current_class != prev_class:
        if prev_class is not None:
            ax2.axvspan(start_idx, i, color=prev_class, alpha=0.5)
        start_idx = i
        prev_class = current_class
# Fill the last region
if prev_class is not None:
    ax2.axvspan(start_idx, end, color=prev_class, alpha=0.5)

# first row for prediction (X_unseen, y_pred)
ax1.plot(Xt, color='blue')
ax1.set_title('Prediction')

# second row for ground truth (X_unseen, y_true)
ax2.plot(Xt, color='blue')
ax2.set_title('Ground Truth')

# plot
plt.show()

Basically, this code is plotting in same figure where first row is prediction and second row is ground truth. I want remove distance of blank area (white) between them.

When you create the subplots, you can specify the amount of space ("height") between the subplots, and set it to zero, with:
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(20, 8), gridspec_kw={"hspace": 0})

Both plots seem to have the same x-axis, so you can also share the x-axis by instead using:
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(
    2,
    1,
    figsize=(20, 8),
    sharex=True,
    gridspec_kw={"hspace": 0},
)

To remove the whitespace at the edges you can just explicitly set the x-axis limits, e.g.,
ax2.set_xlim([start, end])

This should apply across both axes due to the sharing.
